# НЕ ПОНИМАЮ ГДЕ ОШИБКА С++!

Tags: c++, олимпиада

МОЙ КОД:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n,mx1=-1000000000,mx2=-1000000000,mn1=1000000000,mn2=1000000000;
  vector <int> t(n);
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>t[i];
  }
  for (int c=0;c<n;c++){
    if (t[c]>0&&t[c]>mx1){
      mx2=mx1;
      mx1=t[c];
    }else if (t[c]<0&&t[c]<mn1){
      mn2=mn1;
      mn1=t[c];
    }
  }
  if ((mx1*mx2)>(mn1*mn2)){
    cout<<mx2<<" "<<mx1;
  }else{
    cout<<mn1<<" "<<mn2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Максимальное произведение
В массиве, заполненном произвольными целыми числами, найдите два числа, произведение которых максимально. Вложенные циклы не используйте.

Входные данные

На вход программе сначала подаётся значение n⩽50000 — количество элементов в массиве. В следующей строке входных данных расположены сами элементы массива — целые числа, по модулю не превосходящие 30000.

Выходные данные

Выдайте два искомых числа в порядке возрастания.

Comment: Если что я не понимаю что в коде не так, я его написал и ошибок не вижу сколько бы не смотрел( ПОМОГИТЕ ПЖ!!!!!

Comment: Где то я сегодня уже видел этот заголовок.. и написан он был такими же крупными буквами...

Comment: *"На вход программе сначала подаётся значение n⩽50000"*

Comment: Если код не ваш, то попробуйте спросить того, у кого его взяли

Comment: Основная проблема - использование неинициализированной (без начального значения) переменной *n*. Еще есть недочет в алгоритме: рассмотрите случаи, когда в массиве **только** положительные/отрицательные числа или положительное/отрицательное число только одно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да как минимум вы не считали значение `n`...

Но вы как-то уж очень длинно решаете. Вот такой вариант не хотите рассмотреть?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> v[i];
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    if (v[0]*v[1] > v[v.size()-1]*v[v.size()-2])
        cout << v[0] << " " << v[1];
    else
        cout << v[v.size()-2] << " " << v[v.size()-1];
}
```

По крайней мере [проверку](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=1571) (кстати, всегда указывайте URL проверяющей системы, так больше шансов получить ответ) проходит.

Comment: К сожалению `sort` предполагает вложенные циклы...

Comment: @avp Рекурсию, а не вложенные циклы :) По крайней мере в VC++. Только в условии ничего не говорится об *опосредованном* использовании циклов, нет?

Comment: Это верно. А опосредованно любую задачу можно на верхнем уровне  вообще 3-мя строчками представить

Comment: @avp Снимаю шляпу. У меня 3 строчки одни только `#include`'ы заняли...

Comment: Ладно, @Harry. Как вы там поживаете? Зарплату-то платят? У меня, как подумаю о вас всех|, прямо кошки на душе скребут

Comment: @avp Ну так à la guerre comme à la guerre... В науке финансирование, понятно, срезано, но пока хотя бы хватает на голую ставку, без всяких за степень и стаж. Но все же по сравнению с другими городами у нас по крайней мере пока (?) поспокойнее, хотя и к нам прилетало...

Comment: Быстрей бы все это закончилось

Comment: @avp Если бы это зависело от меня — оно бы и не начиналось :) Совершенно дурацкая затея.